# Filter with treeview

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion

I am experiencing problems using a treeview filter. I have made following method:

```
var tree = 
[{
    id: "Arvore",
    text: "Arvore",
    children: [
        {
            id: "Folha_1",
            text: "Folha 1",
            children: [
                {
                    id: "Folha_1_1",
                    text: "Folha 1.1",
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: "dd",
                            text: "abc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_2",
            text: "Folha 2"
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_3",
            text: "Folha 3"
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_4",
            text: "Folha 4"
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_5",
            text: "Folha 5"
        }
    ]
}];

filterData: function filterData(data, value) {
    return data.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.children) item.children = filterData(item.children, value);

        return item.text.indexOf(value) > -1;
    });
},
```

But when I enter text, for example `Folha 1.1`, I want it to return `Arvore > Folha 1 > Folha 1.1`, but the function returns only the first children. What can i do?

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly? search only leaf nodes and return the full path?

Comment: Improved and cleared wording

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. If you want to return the path then you need to check if the item matches OR if it has children left (meaning a child matched).

```js
var tree = 
[{
    id: "Arvore",
    text: "Arvore",
    children: [
        {
            id: "Folha_1",
            text: "Folha 1",
            children: [
                {
                    id: "Folha_1_1",
                    text: "Folha 1.1",
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: "dd",
                            text: "abc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_2",
            text: "Folha 2"
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_3",
            text: "Folha 3"
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_4",
            text: "Folha 4"
        },
        {
            id: "Folha_5",
            text: "Folha 5"
        }
    ]
}];

function filterData(data, value) {
     return data.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.children) item.children = filterData(item.children, value);
        return item.text.indexOf(value) > -1 || (item.children && item.children.length > 0);
    });
}

filterData(tree, "Folha 1.1")
console.log(tree)
```

Comment: Tks man its working, but now my tree filter the last child, example: When i filter for Folha 1.1 the property "abc" stay hide, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
    filterData: function filterData(data, value, forceShow) {
    return data.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.children) item.children = filterData(item.children, value, item.text.indexOf(value) > -1);

        return forceShow || (item.text.indexOf(value) > -1 || (item.children && item.children.length > 0));
    });
},
```